# How can i add custom button to my tinyMCE in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I want to add my shortcode button my tinyMCE editor

this is how my tinyMCE initiate

```
var tinymceSettings = {
            selector: '.wfaq-rich-text',
            height: 150,
            theme: 'modern',
            menubar: '',
            statusbar: false,
            branding: false,
            plugins: 'link image media wordpress wpeditimage lists',
            toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link media | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat',
            image_advtab: false,
            media_advtab: false,
            image_dimensions: false,
            media_dimensions: false,
        };          
        
        if( $('.wfaq-rich-text').length && typeof tinymce != 'undefined' ){
            
            tinymce.init(tinymceSettings);
        }
```

I want to add my custom button which add shortcode `[myshortcode att="30"]` to my selected editor when it clicked

i make a plugin for TinyMCE

```
  tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.wfaq_plugin', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
                // Register command for when button is clicked
                ed.addCommand('wfaq_insert_shortcode', function() {
                    selected = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();

                    if( selected ){
                        //If text is selected when button is clicked
                        //Wrap shortcode around it.
                        content =  ''+selected+'[linespace gap="30"]';
                    }else{
                        content =  '[linespace gap="30"]';
                    }

                    tinymce.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, content);
                });

            // Register buttons - trigger above command when clicked
             ed.addButton('wfaq_button', {title : 'Insert shortcode', cmd : 'wfaq_insert_shortcode', image: false });
        },   
    });

    // Register our TinyMCE plugin
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('wfaq_button', tinymce.plugins.wfaq_plugin);
```

My plugin is not initiate

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this

```
            var tinymceFaqSettings = {
            selector: '.wfaq-rich-text',
            height: 150,
            theme: 'modern',
            menubar: '',
            statusbar: false,
            branding: false,
            plugins: 'link image media wordpress wpeditimage lists wfaq_plugin',
            toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link media | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat | wfaq_button',
            image_advtab: false,
            media_advtab: false,
            image_dimensions: false,
            media_dimensions: false,
            setup: function (editor) {
            editor.addButton('wfaq_button', {
              text: 'Line Gap',
              icon: false,
              onclick: function () {
                editor.insertContent('[linespace gap="20"]');
              }
            });
          }
        };                      
        
        if( $('.wfaq-rich-text').length && typeof tinymce != 'undefined' ){
            
            tinymce.init(tinymceFaqSettings);
        }
```